# Create a string list by combining lists and strings

Tags: python, string, list, zip

I'm trying to create a list that is combining two lists and some strings:

```
string = "test"
list1 = ["1","2","3"]
list2 = ["a","b","c"]

result = ["test.1.a","test.2.b","test.3.b"]
```

I tried messing around with .join and zip functions to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *believe* that a pythonic way could be the following, using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) and `list comprehension`:

```
output = ["{}.{}.{}".format(string, a, b) for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
['.'.join((string,)+i) for i in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Output:

```
['test.1.a', 'test.2.b', 'test.3.c']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "test"
list1 = ["1","2","3"]
list2 = ["a","b","c"]

lst = ['{}.{}.{}'.format(string, list1[x], list2[x]) for x in range(len(list1))]

print(lst)
```

**Output**

```
['test.1.a', 'test.2.b', 'test.3.c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `concatenation` trick:

```
string1 = "test"
list1 = ["1","2","3"]
list2 = ["a","b","c"]

result = [(string1+"."+list1[i]+"."+list2[i]) for i in range(len(list1))]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['test.1.a', 'test.2.b', 'test.3.c']
```

Comment: Multiple string concatenations are less efficient and less readable than using `%` or `format`.

Comment: Others have mentioned about using `%`, That's why I have avoided it

Answer (score 0):

List Comprehension:

```
string = "test"
list(map(lambda x,y: string+"."+x+"."+y, list1,list2))
```

**Output:**

```
['test.1.a', 'test.2.b', 'test.3.c']
```

Comment: `list(map(lambda ...))` is *not* a list comprehension.

Comment: What is the problem in my answer and why it is not a list comprehension?

According to me, List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Because that's not a list comprehension. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions: *A list comprehension consists of brackets containing an expression followed by a `for` clause, then zero or more `for` or `if` clauses.*.

Comment: Note that it's not a good idea to use a lot of string concatenation either. Use string formatting instead.

Comment: In your given doc one list comprehension example is given:

squares = list(map(lambda x: x**2, range(10)))

But in my case, you are saying this is not a list comprehension.

can you please explain why?

Comment: You are misreading the documentation. That's not an example of a list comprehension.

Comment: Also see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries for the reference documentation.